# Compare mean of a variable between two group in RStudio

Tags: r, mean, t-test

This may be the wrong place to ask this question. If so, I apologize.

I have a variable named qualitymean which is the mean of a bunch of likert answer variables:

```
    qualitymean <- rowMeans(subset(please, select = c(PSTFDQ, PHTUDQ, PFOCDQ, PSWIDQ, PHCSDQ, PETRDQ, PEPADQ, PWPTDQ, PHDTDQ, PCAFDQ, PRAPDQ, PTAEDQ, POSRDQ, POTDDQ, POHTDQ, PONADQ)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

I am trying to look at the differences in mean responses by group (IPV_YES and IPV_NO).

I have tried using t.test as followed:

```
    t.test(qualitymean, IPV_YES,
   conf.level = 0.95)
    t.test(qualitymean, IPV_NO,
   conf.level = 0.95)
```

but the means are the same in both groups. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the data.

Comment: Also, what you are doing is to test each mean individually in each group. What you want to do is to test your mean by group, which also means that you need a variable in your data that contains the information about both groups. `t.test(qualitymean~grouping variable`. You also son't need to precalcualte the mean. Instead feed in the raw data.